# why does. button asset appear bigger than area?

Tags: swift, xcode

I currently have a button in a scene/View and the button is set to width 80 and height 80.  It appears the dimensions are correct and I can see the box of dimensions where it should be but the actual image is larger.

[image]

As you can see by the image the button outline appers correct but the whole white box with arrow exceeds it.  You can also see in the width and height the settings are 80.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you set the image as image or background image?

Comment: That was it I had said it as foreground image @son